# Writing data in chunks to excel using OpenXml and appending to the existing rows

Tags: excel, append, openxml

I have a huge data that needs to be written to excel from database in chunks using OpenXML.
I read a set of data ( 1000 rows) from database and write to excel for the first time. I loop and read the second set of data ( next 1000 rows) and have to append it to the existing excel rows.

```cs
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(destination, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
    string relationshipId = sheets.FirstOrDefault(s => string.Compare(s.Name, "Sheet 1", true) == 0).Id;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }
    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);                
    foreach (DataRow dsrow in dt.Rows)
    {                  
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
        foreach (String col in columns)
        {
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }  
         sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);                   
    }
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.ReplaceChild<SheetData>(sheetData, worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how of you do it on SpreadSheetDocument by Microsoft, I have used a more simpler 3rd party DLL which uses SpreadSheetDocument and has minimized the programmer's work.

Anyhow, if you know the specific row index from where the next set of data should be written from, say 1002 in your case (1000 rows and 1 row of header). (Supposedly save in a Session variable or dynamically get the start index by knowing how many rows of data has been written in the excel sheet)

I think you could do something like,

```
int rowIndex = 1002; //This you derive

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
```

Note:
The `{ RowIndex = rowIndex }` should be considered only in the first instance of the loop when you begin appending.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Thanks for the reply. But when I go for second iteration of dataset i am loosing data from first iteration. I mean I look data from row 1 to 1000. But I am able to see data from row 1001 to 2001.

Comment: When you said chunks, do you mean read first set of data, open excel, write and save the excel then again read next set of data, open excel, write and save the excel? If so, I guess the data is overwritten when you run the method the second time after reading the second set of data.

Comment: If all the writing happens in one session (one instance of the application running) I suggest you store the numbers of rows written (DataTable row count) in a Session Variable each time and derive the newRow's index as in the above post. A logical condition should be applied. Session["RowsWritten"] = 1001;// Including RowHeader
if (int.Parse(Session["RowsWritten"].ToString()) > 1) { newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex }; }
else { newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row(); }